# Search part of string at DAX

Tags: powerbi, dax

I'm using below function at Dax and I have some issues.

From what I understood this function should search "*xxxx*" and if it appears in my expression it should give "true" value.

in fact im getting all the time "false" value.

My function:

```
IF(and([product_code_name] = "*titan tidge*",[task_name]  <> "*BURN-in*") ,"CMT 263",(na)
```

Cell data for example: TITAN TIDGE HOST DP

I want to see "CMT 263" data even if my "if" doesn't have full mach.

What im missing here? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only use wildcards like `*` within the `SEARCH()` function (and even then it works a bit differently). Your current function is testing for an exact match.

---

I think you want something along these lines

```
= IF(AND(SEARCH("titan tidge", Table1[product_code_name], 1, 0) > 0,
         SEARCH("BURN-in", Table1[task_name], 1, 0) = 0),
     "CMT 263",
     "(na)")
```

---

For more information on string comparison, check out these articles by Marco Russo:

[From SQL to DAX: String Comparison](https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/from-sql-to-dax-string-comparison/)

[String Comparison in #DAX](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/marco_russo/archive/2011/12/30/string-comparison-in-dax.aspx)

Comment: Thanks it looks like it works... you may have an idea how can I add more  "And" to the expiration? for example ([task_name]<> "ESD") , In addition in your code 1, 0) > 0  = data was found? and  
1, 0) = 0) =  data wasn't found? Thanks,

Comment: Check out the [documentation for SEARCH()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/query-bi/dax/search-function-dax). The function returns the location of the match and the last argument is what to return if no match is found. You can add as many conditions as you want if you use the `&&` operator instead of the `AND()` function (i.e. `a && b && c` instead of `AND(AND(a,b),c)`).